# Using a key (String) as an argument for a method

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am trying to understand methods in Python.I have two classes in my program.

```
class Department(ndb.Model):
  dept_name=ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
  employees=ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)
```

and

```
class Employee(ndb.Model):
   employee_name=ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
   salary=ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

I have this method in the `Department` class

```
def addEmployee(employee):
    dept = Department.get_or_insert("Finance")
    dept.employees.append.(employee.key)
    dept.put()
```

which i am calling from a `RequestHandler` like this:

```
    employee = Employee.get_by_id("David Moyes")
    dept = Department.get_or_insert("Finance")
    dept.addEmployee(employee)
```

I am trying to add `David Moyes` to the `Finance` department.Using his name which is also the key to the `David Moyes` entity in the `Employee` datastore.Problem is,nothing happens and no error message is shown.
I am suspecting the problem is from the line

`def addEmployee(employee):`

When i declare this,what `Type` is `employee`? shouldn't i be passing in a String instead? Since the key is a `String`?

Comment: Im just passing through and have no experience with google app engine, so im sorry if this is a dumb question, but is there a save function you need to be calling in addEmployee()?

Comment: Yes,it is done with `dept.put()`

Comment: Do you need to be passing `self` in addEmployee?  and then `self.append(employee.key)` and `self.put()`?  If these are dumb suggestions, im going to stop overstepping my bounds

Comment: Lol.No such thing as dumb in here.I'll try it

Comment: I'll add it in the answers to be more explicit so what im suggesting is clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to instance methods is a handle to the current object, and should be called `self`. [This is standard python oo programming](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

Also, loading dept inside the `addEmployee` method makes no sense - it is hard coded to load "Finance" - what if you wanted to add an employee to the Sales dept?

I think your `Department` class should look something more like this:

```
class Department(ndb.Model):
  dept_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
  employees = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Employee, repeated=True)

  def addEmployee(self, employee):
    self.employees.append(employee.key)
    self.put()
```

Note I have also added `kind=Employee` to the employees `KeyProperty`, which will validate that you only add Keys of type `Employee` to the list.

Comment: I tried adding `kind=Employee` to my code but i get an error saying `NameError: name Employee is not defined`.

Comment: make sure your Employee class is defined above your Department class